# How to create graph in ArangoDb using arangosh command line?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to execute following JS file using `arangosh` in order to build my graph. The file executes without error but when I go into web interface, I do see a graph created but no vertices or edges in the graph.

```
db._dropDatabase("database");

db. _createDatabase("database", [], [{username: "admin", passwd: "admin", active: true}]);
db._useDatabase("database");

var graph_module =  require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
var graph = graph_module._create("myGraph");

//Add top level documents
graph._addVertexCollection("users");
graph._addVertexCollection("positions");

graph._extendEdgeDefinitions(graph_module._relation("has_worked_at", ["users"], ["positions"]));
```

I save this file as `database.js` and then run following command

```
arangosh --javascript.execute database.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph was created, the two vertex collections and the edge collection as well, but they do not contain any documents (vertices and edges). If you add

```
db.users.insert({_key:"Max"});
db.positions.insert({_key:"ArangoDB"});
db.has_worked_at.insert("users/Max", "positions/ArangoDB", {developer:true});
```

to your script, you will see two vertices and an edge in the graph viewer.

Comment: Also works by using the collections via the graph module: `var user1 = graph.users.insert({_key: "user1", name: "John Doe"}); var user2 = graph.users.insert({_key: "user2", name: "Jane Smith"}); var pos1 = graph.positions.insert({name: "junior manager"}); var pos2 = graph.positions.insert({name: "senior manager"}); var pos3 = graph.positions.insert({name: "developer"}); graph.has_worked_at.insert(user1._id, pos1._id, {company: "ACME corp."}); graph.has_worked_at.insert(user1._id, pos2._id, {company: "Sample inc."}); graph.has_worked_at.insert(user2._id, pos2._id, {company: "Foobar LLC"});`